# How to fix 'segmentation fault (core dumped)' error?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

My code works as intended but at the end it gives the 'segmentation fault (core dumped)' error. I read online this means I'm trying to access memory that I'm not supposed to access but I'm not sure how to fix this. The program is supposed to sort and print the arguments given in the terminal by ASCII order.

This is the code:

```
#include<unistd.h>

int     c_strcmp(char *str1, char *str2)
{
        int     i;

        i = 0;
        while (str1[i] || str2[i])
        {
                if (str1[i] > str2[i])
                        return (1);
                if (str1[i] < str2[i])
                        return (-1);
                i++;
        }
        return (0);
}

void    c_putstr(char *str)
{
        int     i;

        i = 0;
        while (str[i])
        {
                write(1, &str[i], 1);
                i++;
        }
        write(1, "\n", 1);
}

int     main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int     i;
        char    *temp;

        i = 1;
        while (i < (argc - 1))
        {
                if (c_strcmp(argv[i], argv[i + 1]) > 0)
                {
                        temp = argv[i];
                        argv[i] = argv[i + 1];
                        argv[i + 1] = temp;
                        i = 0;
                }
                i++;
        }
        i = 0;
        while (i < argc)
        {
                i++;
                c_putstr(argv[i]);
        }
}
```

It's a school assignment and I'm only allowed to use the 'write' function.

Here are 2 examples of the output I'm getting:

```
a2-r2-p8% ./a.out test2 test3 test1 test4 | cat -e
test1
test2
test3
test4
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./a.out test2 test3 test1 test4 | 
zsh: done                              cat -e
```

```
a2-r2-p8% ./a.out abg b cdf abc z azz | cat -e
abc
abg
azz
b
cdf
z
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./a.out abg b cdf abc z azz | 
zsh: done                              cat -e
```

So, the program does sort and print correctly but gives an error at the end anyway.
Anybody know what I could do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last loop

```
i = 0;
while (i < argc)
{
    i++;
    c_putstr(argv[i]);
}
```

you check `i` but then increment it *before* indexing. This means the last element processed is the sentinel value `NULL` which you will try to dereference in the output function.

So move `i++;` down, and start from `1` if you don't want to report the executable name

```
i = 1;
while (i < argc)
{
    c_putstr(argv[i]);
    i++;
}
```